# How to know if a component is moved relative to the screen (not relative to its parent)?

Tags: java, swing, location, screen, componentlistener

I have a component in a `JFrame` and I need to know when the component is moved relative to the screen space.

It happens either when the frame is moved, either when the layout is changed.

My problem:

- When I attach a `ComponentListener` to my component and that the
  frame is moved, the callback method `componentMoved()` is not called
  because the component has still the same location with regards to its
  parent (here the `JFrame`)
- I would like to know when the component is    moved without add a
  `ComponentListener` to the `JFrame` itself...

So I'm looking a way to know when a component is moved relative to the screen.

Note: These specifications are imposed to me... I have no other choice but it would be to long and irrelevant to explain that here.

Comment: *"it would be to long and irrelevant to explain that here."*  ..Next!

Answer (score 1):

Use `SwingUtilities`. Pass just (0,0) point and see the resultting coordinates

```
public static void convertPointToScreen(Point p,Component c)
```

You listener should be attached to the component containing frame

Comment: Ok, I know how convert location, but I need to be warned dynamically and my problem is that I must not attach a listener to the JFrame.

Comment: Why can't you attach listeners to JFrames?

Comment: As I said it is very long to describe... I take over some code in a company (awful code...) and I have no choice.

Comment: If you have the component you can get it top level ancestor (window, dialog or frame) and add your listener there.